# Creating Multiple Templates

Tags: vba, excel

I have below macro which create multiple templates from Template file and change values based on Sample file. There are some blank cells in that Column. I want VBA to skip those columns and move to next one. Below macro run fine but don't skip blank cells. Any idea how to make it better?

```
Sub Template()

Dim i As Long, N As Long, A As Variant, B As Variant, j As Long
N = Range("P9999").End(xlUp).Row

j = 5

For i = 1 To N

   If Cells(j, 16).Value = "" Then
            j = j + 1
            Else: j = j
            End If
    Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
   A = Sheets("RR9 Sample ").Range("P" & j).Value
   B = Sheets("RR9 Sample ").Range("O" & j).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value = A
    ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value = B

j = j + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: because j=j+1 could be blank also, you need to have the end if from the blank check after the copying part, so after the 2nd j=j+1, which negates the first, so I'd remove your first j=j+1 and have `If Cells(j, 16).Value <> "" Then ........ end if j=j+1`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have created below code as per your recommendation. However it's creating only one template file. Please check it.
Dim i As Long, N As Long, A As Variant, B As Variant, j As Long
N = Range("P9999").End(xlUp).Row

j = 5

For i = 1 To N

   If Cells(j, 16).Value <> "" Then
            
    Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    A = Sheets("RR9 Sample ").Range("P" & j).Value
    B = Sheets("RR9 Sample ").Range("O" & j).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value = A
    ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value = B
   End If
j = j + 1

Next i

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be after this

```
Sub Template()

    Dim j As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    j = 5
    With Sheets("RR9 Sample")
        For Each cell In .Range("P1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
            If cell.value <> "" Then
                j = j + 1
                Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Range("E9").value = cell.value
                ActiveSheet.Range("E10").value = cell.Offset(, -1).value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

or, you can use `SpecialCells` method of `Range` object

```
Sub Template()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    j = 5
    With Sheets("RR9 Sample")
        For Each cell In .Range("P1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            j = j + 1
            Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Range("E9").value = cell.value
            ActiveSheet.Range("E10").value = cell.Offset(, -1).value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting object doesn't support this property or method error on below line. ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value = .cell.Value      Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: sorry, there where some wrong "dots" : see edited answer

Comment: 1st one working perfectly fine except one thing that it includes header as well which is on range("P1").  2nd one is not skipping blank cells.